# Custom encoding for BinaryReader?

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding

I have a file that seems to mix encoding in it. It seems like a Unicode encoded file, but the character length string is encoded like a UTF8 or similar. Here is an example:

```
05 41 00 72 00 69 00 61 00 6C 00
5  A  .  r  .  i  .  a  .  l  .
```

In this example it stores the string like Unicode, using the extra character, but the length of the string is half of what it should be, 05 instead of 0A, as if it were encoded as UTF8.

If I use:

```
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open), Encoding.Unicode))
{
  temp = reader.ReadString();
}
```

When I run this then temp = "Ar"

How can I correctly read this type of encoding? I assume I have to create my own encoding but I don't know how to start on that.

EDIT:

This works. But is there a better way?

```
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open), Encoding.Unicode))
{
  tempByte = reader.ReadByte();
  var length = Convert.ToInt32(tempByte) * 2;
  byteArray = reader.ReadBytes(length);
  for (var ww = 0; ww < length; ww = ww + 2)
  {
    tempString = tempString + (char)byteArray[ww];
  }
}
```

Comment: Utf16, not utf8.  Seems it encoded the number of characters instead of bytes.  Send it back, you don't want it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is being generated by some software that we have no control over.

Comment: Hmya, we don't either of course.  Not sure what you expect here.  If you can count on the bug not getting fixed then just read the byte and multiply by 2 to pass to ReadBytes(), Encoding.Unicode.GetString() to convert.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I have just added some working code. I'm not very experienced with this. I'm not sure how to use what you suggested: ReadBytes(), Encoding.Unicode.GetString()

Comment: This got answered perfectly on CodeReview by Svick:

http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41666/custom-encoding-for-binaryreader/42520#42520